# Loading a JSON file vs querying MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, web, database

It is a performance question - I created a web app (in Node.js) that loads a JSON file that has around 10 000 records and then displays that data to the user. I'm wondering if it would be faster to use (for example) MongoDB(or any other noSQL database, CouchDB?) instead? And how much faster would it be?

Comment: Did you ever complete any performance tests? My Atlas costs are becoming fairly expensive so I'm debating just saving and loading from local JSON as well!

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for speed, JSON is quite specifically "not-fast". JSON involves sending the Keys along with the Values and it requires some heavy parsing on the receiving end. Reading the data from file can be slower than reading from the DB. I wouldn't like to say which is better, so you'll have to test it.